How do I use a scheduler with a lightning module?
Pretty self explanatory, I'm trying to use a ReduceLROnPlateau scheduler in my lightning module but I can't seem to get it to actually change the learning rate. I've put the lr to 0.1 on purpose to have it be artificially high but still it stays throughout training. I also made a dummy dataset that only holds 10 samples so I can run 100 epochs. Even after 100 epochs lr stays the same. appreciate any help in advance.
class STARCOP_module(L.LightningModule):

    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters(ignore=["model"])
        self.model = model
        self.score = BinaryF1Score().to(device)
        self.lr = 0.1
        
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        #torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        X = batch["X"]
        targets = batch["Y"]
        pred = self.model(X)
        loss = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, targets)
        F1_train = self.score(pred, targets)
        self.log("learning rate", self.lr)
        self.log("training loss", loss, prog_bar=False)
        self.log("training F1 score", F1_train)
        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        #torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        X = batch["X"]
        targets = batch["Y"]
        pred = self.model(X)
        v_loss = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, targets)
        F1_val = self.score(pred, targets)
        self.log("validation loss", v_loss)
        self.log("validation F1 score", F1_val)
        return v_loss
    
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        #torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        X = batch["X"]
        targets = batch["Y"]
        pred = self.model(X)
        t_loss = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, targets)
        F1_test = self.score(pred, targets)
        self.log("test loss", t_loss)
        self.log("test F1 score", F1_test)
        return t_loss
    
    def forward(self, input):
        pred = self.model(input)
        return(pred)
        
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.lr)
        sched = {"scheduler": torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer,
                                                               mode="min",
                                                               factor=0.5, 
                                                               patience=1),
                 "monitor": "training loss"}
        return {"optimizer":optimizer, "scheduler":sched}

Also, does anyone know of a way to make it so that the scheduler checks for plateaus per step instead of per epoch?
